# How to fill an open stroke in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

This question seems very simple, but I don't have the design vocabulary to know how to ask the question in proper technical language.

I have created a [tapered line](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-tapered-lines-in-inkscape--vector-23746) in a custom shape, it is the U-shape black line in the image (you can also see the custom shape used to fill along the line, shown in black).

[image: Image: tapered line used to make an open U-shape (black)]

I want to be able to fill this shape, I have been trying for hours. I basically want something like this:

[image: Image: I want to achieve this fill with the U-shape line.]

I guess I am missing something, any ideas?!

Comment: You're showing an image in which you successfully did it.  What's the issue?  You want to fill an area that isn't a defined area.  You need to create a closed shape and then you can fill it.

Comment: Thanks so much for embedding the images. What you see there is something after hours of messing around and I cannot repeat it, unfortunately. How can I convert the stoke to a closed shape without changing its visible appearance? I think that seems to be the main problem.

Comment: I don't use inkscape, but in other graphics software there are typically tools to create a freehand line or shape.  You would start at one of the points and draw a straight line to the other point, then continue around the black portion to eventually return to the starting point, closing the shape.  Then you fill the shape with the color.  The line can either be the same color, or you make the line invisible.  In Photoshop, there is a magnetic lasso that would hug the inside of the shape.  (cont'd)

Comment: Otherwise, you move the new, filled shape to a layer behind the original to hide the excess.  But I'm not familiar with the tools in inkscape.  You basically need an enclosed shape to fill with color.  In some programs that don't use layers, simply drawing a line between the points would create an enclosed area that could be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't (easily) do this is in [the post you quote](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-tapered-lines-in-inkscape--vector-23746):

> A few issues I'd like to point out though.
>
> Since this type of tapering is actually using an ellipse stretched out
>   over a path, this tapered line is essentially just an object being
>   manipulated as a path. This means that the Fill with fill the inside
>   of your line and that the Stroke will put another line outside of your
>   line. Bummer.

There's a way though:

1. Create a tapered path
2. Duplicate it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Open Path Effects dialogue <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>
4. Hide the path effect (close the eye in front of "Pattern Along Path")
5. You can now change the fill colour, and put the filled shape to the back <kbd>End</kbd>

The inconvenience it that you have 2 different shapes, the tapered path and the filled shape, which have distinct control points, so these filling steps should be re-done at each modification of tapered path. For convenience, I recommend to group the tapered path and the filled shape.